# Как в преобразователе организовать вставку темплейта для каждого тега?

Tags: циклы, xslt

Здравствуйте! Черканите, пожалуйста, пару строк, кто разбирается в xsl.
Есть `xml` файл с данными, в нем несколько тегов `<name>`. Так же есть xsl темплейт.
Как в преобразователе организовать вставку этого темплейта для каждого тега `<name>`, то есть столько раз, сколько раз в `xml`-файле встречается указанный тег.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно первый вариант ответа был исчерпывающим, но возможен и другой вариант (боюсь в пару строк не уложусь никак :) ).

Берем как пример такой xml:

```
<names>
    <name>first name</name>
    <name>second name</name>
    <name>third name</name>
</names>
```

Для вывода нескольких элементов можно использовать так же и простой вызов apply-templates

Для этого в xsl прописываем примерно следующее:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/names/name" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/names/name" >
    <p class="name"><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

и получаем нужный результат, три строки и в каждой следующее имя.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp
это вторая строка (ну надо пару строк было)